# how to upload large files in django temp directory location?

Tags: python, django

Here is what I tried to do:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('/home/arvind/Desktop/newupload/documents/'+f.name, 'wb') as destination:
        filepath = destination.name
        for chunk in f.chunks():
           #time.sleep(1)
           destination.write(chunk)


def fileupload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        files = request.FILES.getlist('uploadfile')
        for f in files:
            handle_uploaded_file(f)
        return HttpResponse('add')
    return HttpResponse("done")
```

Comment: Whats the error >?

Comment: complete upload in system tmp directory , after complete upload file move storage location media, but I want simultaneously upload to media
example
i am uploading 1 GB file i want  first 100 MB upload in /tmp dirctory ,then 100mb move to storage location media and next 100 MB